# Reading from large, continuously growing file with BufferedReader

Tags: java, file, large-files, bufferedreader

The task I have is to (somewhat efficiently) read line-by-line through a very large, continuously growing file. Here's basically what I'm doing now:

```
BufferedReader rd = //initialize BufferedReader
String line;
while(true){
    while((line=rd.readLine())==null){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            //handle exception
        }
    }
    //process line
}
```

So my BufferedReader just hangs at the end of the file until there is more stuff to be read. This works pretty well, but there's one problem - If readLine is called while the process that writes to the file is in the middle of writing a line. Then the first call to readLine will return the first section of the line, and the next call will return the second section. But I really need those two parts together, I need complete lines.

More specifically, my problem happens when the following interleaving of events happens:

1. Writing process writes most of a line
2. readLine() is called
3. Writing process finishes that line and adds a newline character
4. readLine() is called

The result is that each readLine() picks up a section of the entire line that the writing process is outputting. It is behaving as expected in doing so because each time it is called, it reaches the end of the file so returns what it has read.

So essentially the functionality I need is a BufferedReader that returns null one readLine earlier; one that does not give you a line until there is a line-break after it, not just EOF after it. So if it finds EOF, it does not return the line up to that point, it returns null, and returns that line once the file has been written to and there's a new line after it.

I could probably implement a crude way of doing this by dealing with the FileReader more directly and essentially re-writing BufferedReader, but I don't know much about how to do this efficiently. My implementation probably won't be as fast as the real BufferedReader, and I'd like to avoid slowing down the program for the times when there *is* data to be read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with the source of BufferedReader and rewrite the 
`String readLine(boolean ignoreLF)` method which causes the trouble if it finds EOF before the end of line. (Unfortunatly it can't be inhertited due to package scope)

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedReader` isn't meant to return null until it's reached the definitive end of the stream. In other words, I wouldn't expect it *ever* to return non-null after it's returned null.

I'm slightly surprised that it's giving you partial lines though - I'd expect it to block until it had a full line.

Comment: I was also surprised to find this out, but it does return non-null after returning null if more is added to the file.

And maybe I should have been more clear about the partial lines - I edited the original question with more description. Problem is that BufferedReader is behaving as expected, it's just that what it does is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You might try http://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/api/gnu/text/LineBufferedReader.html
It gives you capabilities to go back to the start of a line

Answer (score 0):

Try always pushing the last line back, using a [pushback reader](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/pushbackreader.html).

Answer (score 0):

Like stacker said, the best way would be to construct a class that inherit Bufferedreader. What I found is when BufferedReader reached EOF, it is pretty much doomed. If you want to keep reading, or check if there's new stuff, you can always reopen and skip. In practise if you know exactly where to skip to, it wouldn't take long. Take a look at the answer for this question. He created a reopenat() function on a reader, so that the reader is refreshed.

[BufferedReader reset fail after read to end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620030/bufferedreader-reset-fail-after-read-to-end-of-file/24620470?noredirect=1#comment38193054_24620470)