# BufferedReader reset fail after read to end of file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, reset, eof

I have a BufferedReader wrapped on a file, I want to mark a place and use reset() later to get back to this position. I have read the java api, it states mark (readlimit), when read too many bytes, the reset will fail. So i figure I can set a large limit.

However if i have code

```
BufferedReader br=...;
br.mark(1024000); // large but not as large as file. 
while(br.ready()){
    //keep reading. to find some stuff. 
}
//now the br.ready() is false
br.reset() // It will fail with mark invalid exception
```

I think the problem is when br reach end of file, the br is no longer ready, and reset fails....I can manage to keep reading until the 2nd last line and stop, but then how do I do that?

I found that an ugly solution would be using PushbackReader, to save all the stuff I read and push back after the while loop. I am wondering if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missed the [documentation of mark()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#mark(int)) where it clearly states

> Parameters:
>   readAheadLimit - Limit on the number of characters that may be read while still preserving the mark. After reading this many characters, attempting to reset the stream may fail.

so if you want to fully read the stream and `reset()` afterwards you need to call `mark()` with a parameter that is as least as big as the rest of your file.

But as the documentation for [BufferedReader.html#mark(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark(int)) adds

> A limit value larger than the size of the input buffer will cause a new buffer to be allocated whose size is no smaller than limit. Therefore large values should be used with care.

So if memory is a concern, consider if you can incorporate the search and other processing steps or reopen the source between both steps. Surely there is also a way to utilize [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) which has the ability to freely seek through any given file, but won't provide you with characters or strings.

You can maybe utilize `getReadCharacters()` and `reopenAt(BigInteger)` of this class (not properly tested drop-in replacement for `BufferedReader`s acting upon files):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

/**
 * Created by TheConstructor for http://stackoverflow.com/a/24620470/1266906.
 */
public class MarkableFileReader extends Reader {
    /**
     * Cached instance of {@link java.math.BigInteger} of value
     * {@link Long#MAX_VALUE} (used in {@link #skip(java.math.BigInteger)})
     */
    public static final BigInteger LONG_MAX_VALUE                    = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    /**
     * Default value of {@link #reopenOnResetThreshold} (10 MiB)
     */
    public static final int        DEFAULT_REOPEN_ON_RESET_THRESHOLD = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    /**
     * Initialize the line-reading-buffer to this size
     */
    public static final int        EXPECTED_LINE_LENGTH              = 80;

    private final File           file;
    private final Charset        charset;
    private       BufferedReader reader;
    private       BigInteger     readCharacters;
    private       BigInteger     mark;
    private       boolean        reopenOnReset;
    private final int            reopenOnResetThreshold;
    private final BigInteger     reopenOnResetThresholdBI;
    /**
     * {@link java.io.BufferedReader#readLine()} is implemented to skip the
     * {@code '\n'} of an {@code "\r\n"} only with the next read. The same
     * behaviour is implemented here.
     */
    private       boolean        skipLf;
    private       boolean        skipLfMark;

    public MarkableFileReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this(fileName, null);
    }

    public MarkableFileReader(String fileName, Charset charset) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this(fileName, charset, DEFAULT_REOPEN_ON_RESET_THRESHOLD);
    }

    public MarkableFileReader(String fileName, Charset charset, int reopenOnResetThreshold)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        this(new File(fileName), charset, reopenOnResetThreshold);
    }

    public MarkableFileReader(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this(file, null, DEFAULT_REOPEN_ON_RESET_THRESHOLD);
    }

    public MarkableFileReader(File file, Charset charset, int reopenOnResetThreshold) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super();
        this.file = file;
        this.charset = charset;
        this.mark = null;
        this.skipLfMark = false;
        this.reopenOnReset = false;
        this.reopenOnResetThreshold = Math.max(0, reopenOnResetThreshold);
        this.reopenOnResetThresholdBI = BigInteger.valueOf(this.reopenOnResetThreshold);
        initReader();
    }

    private void initReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        final FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = (charset == null) ?
                                                    new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream) :
                                                    new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, charset);
        reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        this.readCharacters = BigInteger.ZERO;
        this.reopenOnReset = true;
        this.skipLf = false;
    }

    private void incrementReadCharacters() {
        this.readCharacters = this.readCharacters.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }

    private void incrementReadCharacters(final long characters) {
        if(characters != -1) {
            this.readCharacters = this.readCharacters.add(BigInteger.valueOf(characters));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            final int read = reader.read();
            if (read != -1) {
                incrementReadCharacters();
            }
            if (skipLf && read == '\n') {
                skipLf = false;
                return read();
            }
            return read;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if ((off < 0) || (len < 0) ||
                    ((off + len) > cbuf.length) || ((off + len) < 0)) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            } else if (len == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            if(skipLf) {
                int firstChar = read();
                if (firstChar == -1) {
                    return 0;
                }
                cbuf[off] = (char) firstChar;
                if (len > 1) {
                    final int read = reader.read(cbuf, off + 1, len - 1);
                    incrementReadCharacters(read);
                    return read + 1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            } else {
                final int read = reader.read(cbuf, off, len);
                incrementReadCharacters(read);
                return read;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads a line of text.  A line is considered to be terminated by any one
     * of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
     * followed immediately by a linefeed.
     * <p>Note: this is not directly proxied to
     * {@link java.io.BufferedReader#readLine()} as we need to know how many
     * characters compose the line-ending for {@link #getReadCharacters()} to
     * return correct numbers</p>
     *
     * @return A String containing the contents of the line, not including
     * any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the
     * stream has been reached
     * @throws IOException
     *         If an I/O error occurs
     * @see java.nio.file.Files#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.charset.Charset)
     * @see java.io.BufferedReader#readLine()
     */
    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            final CharArrayWriter charArrayWriter = new CharArrayWriter(EXPECTED_LINE_LENGTH);
            int lastRead = read();
            if(lastRead == -1) {
                return null;
            }
            while (lastRead != -1 && lastRead != '\r' && lastRead != '\n') {
                charArrayWriter.write(lastRead);
                lastRead = read();
            }
            if(lastRead == '\r') {
                skipLf = true;
            }
            return charArrayWriter.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        if (n < 0L) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("skip value is negative");
        }
        if(n == 0L) {
            return 0L;
        }
        synchronized (lock) {
            if(skipLf) {
                int read = read();
                if (read == -1) {
                    return 0;
                }
                final long skip = reader.skip(n - 1);
                incrementReadCharacters(skip);
                return skip + 1;
            } else {
                final long skip = reader.skip(n);
                incrementReadCharacters(skip);
                return skip;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean ready() throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return reader.ready();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean markSupported() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void mark(int readAheadLimit) throws IOException {
        if(readAheadLimit < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("readAheadLimit needs to be 0 or greater");
        }
        synchronized (lock) {
            mark = readCharacters;
            skipLfMark = skipLf;
            reopenOnReset = false;
            if (reader.markSupported()) {
                if (readAheadLimit >= reopenOnResetThreshold) {
                    reader.mark(reopenOnResetThreshold);
                } else {
                    reader.mark(readAheadLimit);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (mark == null) {
                throw new IOException("call mark() first");
            }
            final BigInteger readSinceMark = readCharacters.subtract(mark);
            if (reopenOnReset ||
                    readSinceMark.compareTo(reopenOnResetThresholdBI) >= 0 ||
                    !reader.markSupported()) {
                if (!reopenAt(mark)) {
                    throw new IOException("reopening at position failed");
                }
            } else {
                reader.reset();
                readCharacters = mark;
            }
            skipLf = skipLfMark;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            reader.close();
        }
    }

    public BigInteger getReadCharacters() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return readCharacters;
        }
    }

    public boolean reopenAt(final BigInteger position) throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
            initReader();
            BigInteger skip = skip(position);
            return skip.equals(position);
        }
    }

    public BigInteger skip(final BigInteger n) throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            BigInteger remaining = n;
            while (remaining.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0) {
                long skip = skip(remaining.min(LONG_MAX_VALUE).longValue());
                remaining = remaining.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(skip));
                if (skip < 1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return n.subtract(remaining);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have changed the readlimit to a larger than the file. But my hypothesis that if the reader reached eof, reset will fail is still correct. I don't think this is documented anywhere, but your markablereader greatly helped solving this problem. Thanks so much

Comment: Slightly moodified my new skip(BigInteger)-function so it will stop when the BufferedReader refuses to skip any more characters.

Comment: Just realized that readLine() would lead to a wrong character count as the line-endings are not returned. Fixed that. Also added synchronized(lock) to public methods to comply with `Reader` expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

> large but not as large as file

This is the problem. Make it as large, or larger. You can't reset further back than the mark quantum.

But you shouldn't have to re-read files at all, this is poor design and poor programming. Compilers can compile programs by only reading source files once, and compilation is a lot more complex than any process you have to carry out.

Comment: While certainly this can be archieved, this can mean that you need to store everything in memory or interweave complex processing methods. Surely both ways can increase the overall performance of the programm.

Comment: It only means you have to store everything in memory if the last line depends on the first line. This is most unusual.

Comment: You can usually refrain from storing the file in memory and just keep preprocessed tokens. Parsing XML e.g. requires to know which tag was opened first, when reading the last line.