# Is there a way for BufferedReader to give last instance a particular character was read?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, eol

I want my BufferedReader to give me the last 'End of Line' instance, so that I can then `mark()` this position and `reset()` to this instance.

I have the following code so far:

```
do {
                int token = st.nextToken();
                switch (token) {
                    case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
                        System.out.println("End of File encountered.");
                        eof = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (token == '\n' || token == '\r') 
                        {
                            System.out.println("End of Line");
                            // mark invoked at this position
                            br.mark(0);
                        }
                        if (token == '\'' || token == '\"') {
                            if (st.sval.length() == 3) {
                                if (isNumeric(st.sval)) {
                                    //output to the CSV File
                                    //System.out.println("Writing to File");
                                    out.println("File Name: " + fileName);
                                    out.println("Code Number: " + st.sval);
                                    out.println("Line Number: " + (st.lineno() + skip));
                                    skip++;
                                    br.reset();
                                    out.println("Line: " + br.readLine());
                                    out.println("-----------------------------------"
                                            + "------------------------------------");
                                    out.println("");
                                    count++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            } while (!eof);
```

I know that this is incorrect as this will mark every End of Line, and resetting results in an infinite loop, I was wondering if there was a way I could reset my buffer to the last 'End of Line' instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would assume that this could work if you change mark(0) to a more resonable number as you mark the stream only after you have read the token. Also you may be interrested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620030/bufferedreader-reset-fail-after-read-to-end-of-file/24620470#24620470

Comment: This would mark every End Of Line though, I want to be able to choose to read an End of Line when the 3 nested If conditions are met

Comment: So do that. What's the problem here?

Comment: Yes and every call to `mark()` will replace the previous mark. As long as you can not check the conditions beforehand I see no other way.

Comment: `reset()` will always try to return to the position of the latest `mark()` call

Comment: I have tried changing mark(0) to mark(10000), however this is resulting an infinite loop

Comment: How do you initialize your `StreamReader`(?) do you create it upon the `BufferedReader`?

Comment: I think you meant my StreamTokenizer? 

This is how I initialized:

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputFile);
StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(br);

Comment: I never get token to be `'\n'` and it terminates just fine after finishing to read everything. Right now I think you were better of switching to `read()` on  `BufferedReader`. Also an example input/output could help.